# silverlight4 MVVM how to editi an EF4 on a grid using two forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

C# VS2010 SL4 MVVM EF4

need to replace edit in place on a datagrid.

any one can point me to a SL4 MVVM sample code. the requirements are as follows:

I have 2 usercontrols.
One shows an Edit button and a Datagrid where each row is containing an EF object.
 the other is just a usercontrol with a textboxes and a Savebutton. (is called edit form)

the user selects from grid a row containing an EF object an click the edit button to change it. 
the grid is replaced by the edit form showing the contents of the selected row,
 user applies changes to the data and clicks the SaveButton. 
this edit forms now closes and
the changed row now shows the row with editted values.

thanks.

Comment: Do/Will you have a ViewModel for each UserControl?

Comment: I beleive is better to do ViewModel for each UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DataForm in the Silverlight toolkit.  You can set the CurrentItem on the DataForm to the SelectedItem from the DataGrid.

Comment: thanks. Yes it may help a control as you describe, but how does it work from my datagrid on a mvvm framework? 
am looking for a simmilar proj where I can see some master detail.